# Percona server weird bugs

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, percona

I run a SaaS system on AWS using Percona, MySQL (from Oracle) and Aurora (from AWS). We rely heavily on stored procedures and stored functions with the front end being a .NET app that connects using the MySQL .NET connector. All environments are identical in terms of databases, stored procedures, etc, but host different clients data (I basically shard by client space).

The system is several years old but is under continuous active development.

After a recent upgrade to Percona we started getting random errors, only from the percona servers, that stored functions do not exist. The functions do exist, and the errors go away on their own. They pop up randomly over the course of the day. The issues do not happen on the identically configured, identical structure, identical code, MySQL or Aurora servers.

To try to resolve the issue I upgrade to percona server 5.6.27. The problem did NOT go away but right after the upgrade we started having character set problems with a piece of code that concats a long set of integers and returns a mediumtext through a stored function call. If we run a find_in_set on the returned result it dies with a UTF8 character set error.

e.g. inside the stored procedure, the code that fails looks something like this:

```
declare list mediumtext;
set list:=fn_getMyBigText();
if find_in_set(123,list) then
  select 'worked';
end if;
```

The error is something like this:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...' for column 'list' at row 1
```

You can do a select on the variable and view it in Workbench or from the command line and it shows it has the correct data, it only fails when using it inside find_in_set()

All character set variables are set to utf8 and all collations are set to uf8_general_ci. The code base did not change. i.e. it worked immediately before the upgrade and failed immediately after. Running the same code on Aurora and MySQL works just fine. All the databases, tables, and columns are set to utf8, there is no other character set in sight.

I tried converting the code to use mediumblob instead of mediumtext since the blob has no notion of character set and the error persisted. It is like the code internally is doing an implicit convert to latin1.

Short of switching off percona, is there anything else out there that I am missing? some setting that I am missing?

thanks.

Comment: From first glance, it looks like it's a problem with the return value of fn_getMyBigText() function.   Are you able to share the definition of that function?

Also,  you're not seeing this behavior with the base Oracle 5.6.27?

Comment: Thanks @DavidH.Bennett, we ended up switching to the Oracle's version of MySQL 5.6 community edition and that fixed the issue.  The function definition looks like this: CREATE FUNCTION `fn_getMyBigText`( _viewcustomerId int, _userId int, _employeeId bigint)  RETURNS mediumtext deterministic
BEGIN ...